# Add min value of a group in only the last row of the group with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to compute the min value of 2nd column which belong to a certain 1st column values.
so my dataframe is as follows:

```
name        CEMS    star
ACC         CEMS-1  3
ACC         CEMS-2  4
ACC         CEMS-3  5
ACC         CEMS-4  5
ARTi        CEMS-1  4
ARTi        CEMS-2  5
ARTi        CEMS-3  4
ARTi        CEMS-4  5
```

Now I want to find a minimum star value for each name in a separate column from the different values of CEMS

I want my dataframe to look like this:

```
Name            CEMS    star  min
ACC         CEMS-1        3    
ACC         CEMS-2        4     
ACC         CEMS-3        5     
ACC         CEMS-4        5     3
ARTi        CEMS-1        4     
ARTi        CEMS-2        5     
ARTi        CEMS-3        4     
ARTi        CEMS-4        5     4
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: And your code is?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help center, in particular [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform` isn't enough. You will need to mask everything but the last index. You can perform index aligned assignment to do so.

```
g = df.groupby('name')['star']
df['minstar'] = pd.Series(g.min(), index=g.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index))
```

```
df.fillna('')

   name    CEMS  star minstar
0   ACC  CEMS-1     3        
1   ACC  CEMS-2     4        
2   ACC  CEMS-3     5        
3   ACC  CEMS-4     5       3
4  ARTi  CEMS-1     4        
5  ARTi  CEMS-2     5        
6  ARTi  CEMS-3     4        
7  ARTi  CEMS-4     5       4
```

Comment: Ok, this may sound dumb but can we merge the rows in the "minstar" column to get a collective result ?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "merge"? You could consider opening a new question if you have any more follow ups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupBy` + `transform` with `min`. If your dataframe is also sorted by `name` you can use `drop_duplicates` for your desired output.

```
df['star_min'] = df.groupby('name')['star'].transform('min')\
                   .drop_duplicates(keep='last')

print(df)

   name    CEMS  star  star_min
0   ACC  CEMS-1     3       NaN
1   ACC  CEMS-2     4       NaN
2   ACC  CEMS-3     5       NaN
3   ACC  CEMS-4     5       3.0
4  ARTi  CEMS-1     4       NaN
5  ARTi  CEMS-2     5       NaN
6  ARTi  CEMS-3     4       NaN
7  ARTi  CEMS-4     5       4.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but I edited my question. Care to take a look?

Comment: @Abhishek2332, Sure, but I don't see any material change. I've updated my answer to reflect your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

To change only last value, as in your expected output

```
ind = df.groupby('name', as_index=False).apply(lambda s: s.index[-1])
df.loc[ind, 'min'] = df.groupby('name').star.min().values

    name    CEMS    star    min
0   ACC     CEMS-1  3       NaN
1   ACC     CEMS-2  4       NaN
2   ACC     CEMS-3  5       NaN
3   ACC     CEMS-4  5       3.0
4   ARTi    CEMS-1  4       NaN
5   ARTi    CEMS-2  5       NaN
6   ARTi    CEMS-3  4       NaN
7   ARTi    CEMS-4  5       4.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !